# NodeJS server receiving POST request

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I am creating a simple NodeJS server that will receive a POST request and will perform some business logic

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
if (request.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';
        request.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
        });
        request.on('end', function () {
            try {
              var post = JSON.parse(body);
              deal_with_post_data(request,post);
              response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
              response.end();
              return;
            }catch (err){
              response.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
              response.write("Bad Post Data.  Is your data a proper JSON?\n");
              response.end();
              return;
            }
        });
    }
});
server.listen(3000);
console.log("server started")
```

Now when I test with sample POST request from postman with a json, I get error `Bad Post Data.  Is your data a proper JSON?` which essentially means it got into `500 internal server error`.

Here is the sample JSON I tried

```
{
    "glossary":"book"
}
```

And sending POST request to `http://<IP_ADDRESS>:3000`

Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: What error do you see if you add the line `console.log(err)` after the catch?

Comment: When I run your code, the function `deal_with_post_data` isn't defined, so I get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested your code:

```
const http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
if (request.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';
        request.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
        });
        request.on('end', function () {
            try {
              var post = JSON.parse(body);
              // deal_with_post_data(request,post);
              console.log(post); // <--- here I just output the parsed JSON
              response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
              response.end();
              return;
            }catch (err){
              response.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
              response.write("Bad Post Data.  Is your data a proper JSON?\n");
              response.end();
              return;
            }
        });
    }
});
server.listen(3000);
console.log("server started")
```

In Postman I made a POST request with the given JSON (as `raw`) and I get the proper JSON logged at the console. So the provided code is fine. The problem might be the `deal_with_post_data` function (which you didn't showed here)